# Javascript - How to turn this into a simple function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        // $('.pull-me').click(function()
        // {
        //     $('.login').slideToggle('slow')
        // });

        $('#thumbnail1').mouseenter(function()
        {
            $('#thumbnailTitle1').css('visibility', 'visible')
        });
        $('#thumbnail1').mouseleave(function()
        {
            $('#thumbnailTitle1').css('visibility', 'hidden')
        })


        $('#thumbnail2').mouseenter(function()
        {
            $('#thumbnailTitle2').css('visibility', 'visible')
        });
        $('#thumbnail2').mouseleave(function()
        {
            $('#thumbnailTitle2').css('visibility', 'hidden')
        })


        $('#thumbnail3').mouseenter(function()
        {
            $('#thumbnailTitle3').css('visibility', 'visible')
        });
        $('#thumbnail3').mouseleave(function()
        {
            $('#thumbnailTitle3').css('visibility', 'hidden')
        })
    });
```

I'm very new to Javascript but am trying to learn. I aware this is jQuery but would like to know if there is a quicker way to do this code, like create a smaller function that i can call up to display/hide the text.

Because i will be adding more thumbnails and i don't want to have to write it all out for every photo and text that i display on the photo.

Comment: Can you please HTML for this scenario?

Comment: add a class to all those thumbnails you want to change, then do: `$(".newclass").mouseenter(...)` and `$(".newclass").mouseleave(...)`

Comment: Ah yes, i dont have the HTML with me at the moment i will add it later when i get it.

Comment: In case you got an answer, please consider to up vote + mark as answer the answer that help you solve your issue.

Comment: I Have upvoted everyone that provided a good solution and chosen the solution to an Answer that i think i will use. Thanks everyone for the answers!

Comment: MagicRecon, I suggest you learn the plugin pattern as demonstrated in my answer. It will keep your code much more flexible than the other answers provided here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use classes instead of ID's if you want to target similar elements with a behaviour.

The function itself is correct. The problem is that you have structured your HTML with unique ID's for every image. Trying to fix the problem by writing functions that target your unique ID's is the wrong approach, the underlying problem is your usage of ID's to target the element in the first place.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.thumbnail').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).find('.thumbnail-title').css('visibility', 'visible');
  })

  $('.thumbnail').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).find('.thumbnail-title').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  })

});
```

In the code snippet above you can see that every element with a class of `thumbnail` is selected. When the user hovers over a thumbnail you can reference the currently hovered element (with `$(this)`) and find the child element with the class `thumbnail-title`.

This is the simplest approach to sharing behaviour across elements of the same type.

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wq5r97ep/2/

EDIT: You can of course abstract this away into a plugin or just a general function. But this is the basic idea.

Comment: This is really helpful thanks. This is what i need in order to make my code more friendly and lightweight so to speak. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bind a single event handler using [Multiple Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), In the event handler create the targeted selector using the current element `this` id property.

```
$('#thumbnail1, #thumbnail2, #thumbnail3').hover(function(){
    var selector='#thumbnailTitle'+ this.id.replace(/[^\d.]/g,'');
    $(selector).css('visibility','visible');
}, function(){
    var selector='#thumbnailTitle'+this.id.replace(/[^\d.]/g,'');
    $(selector).css('visibility','hidden');
})
```

However I would recommend you to establish the relationship using custom `data-*` prefixed attribute. Here example

```js
$('.thumbnail').hover(function() {
  $('#' + this.dataset.target).toggleClass('hidden');
}, function() {

  $('#' + this.dataset.target).toggleClass('hidden');
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="thumbnail" data-target="thumbnailTitle1">thumbnail 1</span>
<span class="thumbnail" data-target="thumbnailTitle2">thumbnail 2</span>
<span class="thumbnail" data-target="thumbnailTitle3">thumbnail 3</span>


<div class="hidden" id="thumbnailTitle1">thumbnailTitle1</div>
<div class="hidden" id="thumbnailTitle2">thumbnailTitle2</div>
<div class="hidden" id="thumbnailTitle3">thumbnailTitle3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is an option.

```js
( function( $, window, undefined ) {

  var handle_mouse_events = function handle_mouse_events( thumbnail_selector, thumbnail_title_selector ) {
    
    $( thumbnail_selector ).mouseenter(
      function() {
        $( thumbnail_title_selector ).css( 'visibility', 'visible' );
      }
    );
    
    $( thumbnail_selector ).mouseleave(
      function() {
        $( thumbnail_title_selector ).css( 'visibility', 'hidden' );
      }
    );
    
  };
  
  handle_mouse_events( '#thumbnail1', '#thumbnailTitle1' );
  handle_mouse_events( '#thumbnail2', '#thumbnailTitle2' );
  handle_mouse_events( '#thumbnail3', '#thumbnailTitle3' );

} )( jQuery, this );
```

```css
.image_container > div {
  display : inline-block;
  width : 150px;
  height : 200px;
}

span {
  visibility : hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image_container">
  <div id="thumbnail1">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%97150&w=150&h=150" />
    <span id="thumbnailTitle1">Title #1</span>
  </div>
  <div id="thumbnail2">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%97150&w=150&h=150" />
    <span id="thumbnailTitle2">Title #2</span>
  </div>
  <div id="thumbnail3">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%97150&w=150&h=150" />
    <span id="thumbnailTitle3">Title #3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function handleEventsFor(index) {
  $('#thumbnail' + index).mouseenter(function() {
    $('#thumbnailTitle' + index).css('visibility', 'visible')
  });
  $('#thumbnail' + index).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#thumbnailTitle' + index).css('visibility', 'hidden')
  })
}
```

And call it like this:

```
handleEventsFor(1);
handleEventsFor(2);
```

Or like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  handleEventsFor(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a simple `visibleHover` plugin for it. Using it will work like this

```
$(selectorForThumbnails).visibleHover(selectorForText);
```

Or as the example shows

```
// '.thumbnail' is the class of the parent elements
// 'span' is the selector for the children text elements
$('.thumbnail').visibleHover('span');
```

You can customize these inputs to match any HTML structure you have.

Click the <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button below to see it work

---

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.visibleHover = function(selector) {
    return this.each(function(idx, elem) {
      $(elem).hover(
        function() { $(selector, elem).css('visibility', 'visible'); },
        function() { $(selector, elem).css('visibility', 'hidden'); }
      );
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
  
$('.thumbnail').visibleHover('span');
```

```css
.thumbnail {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.thumbnail .image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.thumbnail span {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <span>Text A</span>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <span>Text B</span>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <span>Text C</span>
</div>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this also,

Lets say your HTML

```
<div id="thumbnails">
   <div><img class="thumbnails" src="" /></div>
   <div><img class="thumbnails" src="" /></div>
   <div><img class="thumbnails" src="" /></div>
   <div><img class="thumbnails" src="" /></div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#thumbnails").find('.thumbnails').mouseenter(function(){
        var visibility = $(this).css('visibility');

        if(visibility == 'hidden'){
            $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    });

    $("#thumbnails").find('.thumbnails').mouseleave(function(){
        var visibility = $(this).css('visibility');

        if(visibility == 'visible'){
            $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Referencing by **ID** (i.e. $('#thumbnailn')) is very specific. You can make broader references by accessing **tags** or other attributes such as **class** instead.

Something like:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="thumbnail1" class="thumbnails"><span id="thumbnailTitle1"></span>...</div>
<div id="thumbnail1" class="thumbnails"><span id="thumbnailTitle2"></span>...</div>
<div id="thumbnail1" class="thumbnails"><span id="thumbnailTitle3"></span>...</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".thumbnails").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children("span").css('visibility', 'visible');
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children("span").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

In the above example I show how to reference a class (i.e. $(".thumbnails")) and a tag (i.e. ("span")) using JQuery

Answer (score -1):

Using JQuery

```
 $('#thumbnail3').mouseleave(function(e)
        {
           $(e.target).hide();
        })
```

Using css.

```
#thumbnail3:hover {display:none}
```

Answer (score -1):

Writing the whole thing inside a loop is one option.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= whatever_your_length_is; i++) {
  $('#thumbnail' + i).mouseenter(function() {
    $('#thumbnailTitle' + i).css('visibility', 'visible');
  };

  $('#thumbnail' + i).mouseleave(function() {
     $('#thumbnailTitle' + i).css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
}
```